# c# Adding Grid view - The class dataGridView1 unrecognized

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview, datagridview

Iv'e set up the connection between my program and MySQL.
I'm trying to show one table in the grid view which i have created.

```
private void Customers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
    conn.Open();

    Grid add_screen = new Grid();
    add_screen.ShowDialog();
    MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter;

    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from customer",conn);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
}
```

The error i get is that "dataGridView1 does not exists in the current context".
I checked that this is the correct name of the button.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `dataGridView1` should not be a`Button`, it should be a `DataGrid` in your WPF. Have you added the `DataGrid` element to your WPF markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you have an error in .design file, try to found it or rebuild the page again, second issue you have is you need to add dataGridView1.databind()